# Opera shows a broken image if image is not exist

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am looking for a way how to prevent the browser of Opera to show the broken image if the image is not found in the path.

[image: broken image]

In mozila, if the image is not exist, then it will be blank without showing a broken image like above.

Comment: that's browser internal behavior, and nothing you can do in your code will change that, except for **NOT** sending out broken image links.

Comment: This may seem trivial, but Why don't you correct your image path rather than correct the broken result of the incorrect image path?...

Comment: Because the images is fetched with PHP, so that it can't be predicted if the image will be there or not while there are a bunch of placeholder in the html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using JS for example. Simplest way:

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.style.display='none'">
```

Or for all images on page:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for( var i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
    (function( i ) {
        images[ i ].onerror = function() {
           images[ i ].style.display = 'none';
        }
    })( i );
}
```